# VSCode keeps removing the last line of 2 empty lines at the EOF

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using a managed VSCode environment (so some settings have been pre-configured for me) and it keeps modifying the empty lines at the end of the file every time I try to save it.

My Dockerfile is auto-generated and has 2 empty lines at the end of the file. However, when I save any modification to the file, it removes one of the empty lines automatically. When I add it back and save it, it still removes it. What is the setting I need to disable to get ride of this behavior?

I was looking at this setting but not sure that this fixes it:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bottom-left corner
[image]
Settings:
[image]
Text Editor -> Files:
[image]
Scroll until you find this setting and uncheck it:
[image]